# Official redux reducer example not clear

Tags: action, redux, reducers

I am trying to understand official Redux reducer example.

I am not sure who calls this "posts" function, why is it separately defined, and why that function has never been exposed to CombineReducer method, but somehow gets invoked when actions are dispatched.

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import {
   SELECT_SUBREDDIT, INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT,
   REQUEST_POSTS, RECEIVE_POSTS
} from './actions'

function selectedSubreddit(state = 'reactjs', action) {
  switch (action.type) {
   case SELECT_SUBREDDIT:
    return action.subreddit
   default:
    return state
  }
}

function posts(state = {
   isFetching: false,
   didInvalidate: false,
   items: []
  }, action) {

   switch (action.type) {
    case INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
       didInvalidate: true
      })
    case REQUEST_POSTS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
       isFetching: true,
       didInvalidate: false
     })
    case RECEIVE_POSTS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        didInvalidate: false,
        items: action.posts,
        lastUpdated: action.receivedAt
      })
    default:
     return state
    }
  }

  function postsBySubreddit(state = { }, action) {
   switch (action.type) {
     case INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT:
     case RECEIVE_POSTS:
     case REQUEST_POSTS:
       return Object.assign({}, state, {
        [action.subreddit]: posts(state[action.subreddit], action)
    })
    default:
      return state
   }
}

 const rootReducer = combineReducers({
   postsBySubreddit,
   selectedSubreddit
 })

export default rootReducer
```

I know that it gets called once by calling postsBySubreddit ( REQUEST_POSTS ), but even later in the process it gets called when action RECEIVE_POSTS is dispatched.

It seems to me like we have multiple listeners in this case to the same actions. Trying to understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `posts` function is called inside of the `postsBySubreddit()` function:

```
case REQUEST_POSTS:
   return Object.assign({}, state, {
    [action.subreddit]: posts(state[action.subreddit], action)
})
```

It's defined separately to make it clear how the logic works.  `postsBySubreddit` is responsible for figuring out *which* subreddit's data should be updated, and `post` is responsible for updating the data for a single subreddit.  It's effectively separation of concerns.  Both functions know how to update some data in response to a given action.

Quoting from the docs:

> At its core, Redux is really a fairly simple design pattern: all your "write" logic goes into a single function, and the only way to run that logic is to give Redux a plain object that describes something that has happened. The Redux store calls that write logic function and passes in the current state tree and the descriptive object, the write logic function returns some new state tree, and the Redux store notifies any subscribers that the state tree has changed.

The key here is that the one "root reducer" function is itself made up of many smaller functions composed together to do the work.  So, in one sense there's only one listener, the root reducer.  But, in another sense, there's many listeners, because the root reducer function is delegating its responsibilities to a number of other functions to do the real work.

I'd encourage you to read through the Redux docs thoroughly.  In particular, you should read [Reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html), the [Redux FAQ](http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html) (particularly the FAQ section on [Reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Reducers.html) ) and the new [Structuring Reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html) section.  Be sure to read through some of the articles listed in [Prerequisite Concepts](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/PrerequisiteConcepts.html) as well.

Comment: The same question for you as for Dave; later when RECEIVE_POSTS is dispatched, I do not understand how "posts" gets invoked. The case RECEIVE_POSTS: in postsBySubreddit does not have any handler function.

Comment: The `postsBySubreddit` function is using a switch statement to handle all three cases the same way.  Remember that by putting multiple cases in a row, you can handle each of the cases with the same code.  So, here all three cases (INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT, RECEIVE_POSTS, and REQUEST_POSTS) will be handled the same way: by calling `posts()` with the data for that specific post, and the current action.

Comment: I get it now. Great answer. Thanks

Comment: Cool. I really do encourage you to continue reading through the docs. There's tons of extremely valuable info in there. Also, I keep a big list of links to high-quality tutorials and articles on React, Redux, and related topics, at https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links .  Specifically intended to be a great starting point for anyone trying to learn the ecosystem.

Comment: I will definitely. Thank you for your help understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality of `REQUEST_POSTS` and `RECEIVE_POSTS` is handled per-subreddit by a reducer called by a "higher-level" reducer.

E.g., `postsBySubreddit` is the reducer exposed via `combineReducers`. Rather than put its functionality into `postsBySubreddit` the action is passed on to the `posts` reducer, which sets and receives *only the state for the given subreddit*:

```
[action.subreddit]: posts(state[action.subreddit], action)
```

There's no reason to expose the `posts` reducer in `combineReducers`; the state is updated by a subreddit-exclusive reducer.

All of the same logic *could* have been handled in `postsBySubreddit`, but that would make `postsBySubreddit` larger and messier. `posts` acts on a (subreddit-sepcific) slice of the state. It's just a separation of concerns.

Specifics:

- It's called by every action handled by `postsBySubreddit`
- It's defined separately so the state slicing is handled in one place (`postsBySubreddit`) and the subreddit-specific state manipulation is handled in one place (`posts`)
- At the top level only `postsBySubreddit` sees the actions--but those messages are delegated to `posts` as with any other refactoring.

Comment: I understand that initial part, but later when RECEIVE_POSTS is dispatched, I do not understand how "posts" gets invoked. The case RECEIVE_POSTS:  in postsBySubreddit does not have any handler function.

Comment: @tito Sure seems like it does; JS case statements fall through.

Comment: @tito No problem :)